# Need create column with type TIMESTAMP but does not update existing rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql, liquibase

I have situation like this:

1. have existing table
2. need add new column using
3. type of the column is TIMESTAMP

Code:

```
<changeSet author="name" id="bla-bla-bla">
    <addColumn tableName="table_name">
        <column name="new_col_name" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

This code creating column, and its cool! But! Its also sets to all existing rows default value to 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

But I need leave all existing rows without changes. And TIMESTAMPS should be set only for new rows.

Comment: `SELECT DATE(0)` and `SELECT TIME(0)` should answer that

Comment: What parameter o what command i need to use for setting NULL as a default value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - MySQL can store 'zero' dates (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - MySQL JDBC driver has no problems loading this value. It is converted to null in Java code.

Comment: @Perception: then you are either using an very old driver (3.x), or you told the driver to explicitely ignore those values. The default behaviour in all drivers since 4.x is to throw an exception. This can be modified using the `zeroDateTimeBehavior` connection property. See the manual for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-j-installing-upgrading.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Using 5.x drivers actually. And yes, you need to set the zeroDateTimeBehavior property. Like I said, MySQL can store 'zero' dates.

Comment: @Perception: just because MySQL *can* store them, doesn't make them valid dates.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - nowhere did I say they were valid. I was refuting misinformation that was posted in comments that ave now been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

A `TIMESTAMP` column in MySQL defaults to `NOT NULL` and that dreaded zero date as the default value ([See the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for details).

The only way I can see how to avoid this, is to modify the generated SQL to include the `DEFAULT NULL` clause in the changeset.

```
<addColumn tableName="foo">
    <column name="new_date" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
</addColumn>
<modifySql>
     <replace replace="TIMESTAMP" with="TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL"/>
</modifySql>
```

Specifying defaultValueDate="NULL" does not seem to work. I guess that's because Liquibase does not know about the `timestamp` quirks of MySQL and thinks it's no necessary to state the obvious - that a column should be filled with `NULL`.

**Edit**

I forgot that this will not work for new rows of course. There are two ways to re-apply the default value using Liquibase:

Adding a second changeSet that changes the default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
<sql>
     alter table foo modify new_date timestamp null default current_timestamp
</sql>
```

Or by not using `DEFAULT NULL` when adding the column, but then running a statement that sets all (existing) rows back to `NULL`. A `sql` tag with `update foo set new_date = null`.

Comment: <addColumn tableName="foo">
    <column name="new_date" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
</addColumn>
<modifySql>
     <replace replace="TIMESTAMP" with="TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL"/>
</modifySql>
Thats also putts NULL to all new rows.

Comment: @lugaru: ah, right. I guess that makes things even uglier. See my edit.

Comment: Can you write an example of the code... im not so familiar with liquibase and that staff)))

Answer (score 0):

one more time, i need modify this code.
The idea is the same, how to create new Timestamp column but all existing row should be modified with current timestamp and only once during updating but all new rows should be with creation timestamps.
Code:

```
<changeSet author="name" id="bla-bla-bla">
    <addColumn tableName="table_name">
        <column name="new_col_name" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

This code creates column with 0000-00-00 time stamps for all existing rows.